# How to create new sheets based on list?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create new workbooks for each group found in sheet10 based on a list of group names from another sheet named GroupFileNames.

To make troubleshooting easier, the current code creates new worksheets instead of workbooks.  I already have the code needed to create workbooks.

My problem is that my code will not loop through the list of group names.  It creates a sheet for the first group (ABC Corp) and copies their corresponding data but it never creates the sheet for the next group (XYZ Corp).

I tried different ways to loop using Do Until, For Each, etc.

```vb
Sub CreateWkBookByGroupName()
    
    
    Dim Transaction() As Variant
    Dim GroupNameTransactions() As Variant
    Dim TransactionCounter As Long
    Dim GpnTransactionCounter As Long
    Dim Counter As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim gfn As Worksheet
    Set gfn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GroupFileNames")
    Dim groupName As String
    
    
    i = 1
    groupName = gfn.Range("A" & i)
    
    'Store entire database in the Transaction array
    Transaction = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'Starting in the i row of the database loop through each transaction
    
    For TransactionCounter = i To UBound(Transaction, 1)
       
        'If the thirteenth column contains a value equal to groupName...
        If Transaction(TransactionCounter, 13) = groupName Then
            '...increase the GpnTransactionCounter by 1
            GpnTransactionCounter = GpnTransactionCounter + 1
            
            'Redimension the GroupNameTransaction array with each instance _
            of a GroupName transaction.
            ReDim Preserve _
              GroupNameTransactions(1 To 13, 1 To GpnTransactionCounter)
            'Start a counter to populate the GroupNameTransactions array
            For Counter = 1 To 13
                'The GroupNameTransactions array equals the current transaction
                GroupNameTransactions(Counter, GpnTransactionCounter) _
                  = Transaction(TransactionCounter, Counter)
            Next Counter
        End If
    Next TransactionCounter
    'Add a new sheet
    Worksheets.Add
    'Add the headings in the first row of the Transactions array
    Range("A1:M1") = Transaction
    'Transpose the GroupNameTransaction array onto the new sheet
    Range("A2", Range("A2").Offset(GpnTransactionCounter - 1, 12)) _
    = Application.Transpose(GroupNameTransactions)
    'Autofit columns
    Columns.AutoFit
    
End Sub
```

This data should produce two new sheets, one for ABC Corp and another for XYZ Corp.  Each new sheet should have all columns that belong to their group.
[image]

This is the list of group names that my code uses to compare to the group names on Sheet10.
[image]

Comment: This can be done easier using a filter.

Comment: You call your Excel Table a Database. I think the tool you really need is a database. You are trying to make views from data. Don't change the data to make a view. Have you tried getting in to MS Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do need to create new sheets that are a a subset of the grouped data then a nested scripting dictionary is a helpful data structure.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateWkBookByGroupName()

    Dim myTransactionsGroupedByName As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myTransactionsGroupedByName = PopulateTransactionsByGroupName
    
    Dim myGroup As Variant
    Dim myWS As Excel.Worksheet
    For Each myGroup In myTransactionsGroupedByName
    
        With myTransactionsGroupedByName
        
            Set myWS = CreateSheetForGroupName(.Item(myGroup))
            myWS.Name = myGroup
        End With
        
    Next
    
End Sub


Public Function CreateSheetForGroupName(ByVal NamedGroup As Scripting.Dictionary) As Excel.Worksheet

    Static myHeadingRow As Excel.Range
    
    If myHeadingRow Is Nothing Then
    
        Set myHeadingRow = NamedGroup.Item(0)
        Set CreateSheetForGroupName = Nothing
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    Dim myWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Set myWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    
    myWS.Range("A1").Value = myHeadingRow
    myHeadingRow.Copy Destination:=myWS.Range("A1")
    Dim myTransaction As Variant
    For myTransaction = 0 To NamedGroup.Count - 1
    
        NamedGroup(myTransaction).Copy Destination:=myWS.Range("A" & CStr(myTransaction + 2))
    
    Next
    
    Set CreateSheetForGroupName = myWS
    
End Function


Public Function PopulateTransactionsByGroupName() As Scripting.Dictionary

    Const GroupNameColumn As Long = 13 'Column number for Group Names
    Dim myTransaction As Variant
    
    Dim myGroupedByName As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set myGroupedByName = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For Each myTransaction In Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows
    
        Dim GroupName As String
        GroupName = myTransaction.Columns(GroupNameColumn).Cells(1, 1).Value
        
        With myGroupedByName
        
            If Not .exists(GroupName) Then
            
                ' First entry will be the heading rows with a key of "GroupName"
                .Add GroupName, New Scripting.Dictionary
                
            End If
            
            With .Item(GroupName)
            
                .Add .Count, myTransaction
                
            End With
        
        End With
    
    Next
    
    Set PopulateTransactionsByGroupName = myGroupedByName
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  When I attempt to run your code, I get a Compile error: User-defined type not defined.  The line with Public Function CreateSheetForGroupName(ByVal NamedGroup As Scripting.Dictionary) As Excel.Worksheet is highlighted after the error.  What could be causing this error?

Comment: You need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (Tools.References) or change New Scripting.Dictionary to CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary").  The former allows intellisense due to early binding, the latter does not offer intellisense as it is late bound  If you are new to VBA or Scripting.DIctionaries I'd recommend the former approach.

Comment: I added the Scripting Runtime reference as you advised but now there is a new error. Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.  The highlighted line is line 15 that reads myWS.Name = myGroup.

Comment: Use the locals window to look at  the values of the variables in the affected method.  This should help you understand what is happening.  The code worked fine on my PC using the sample dataset you provided.

Comment: I stepped through your code and noticed that myWs = Nothing.  The issued came from the Public Function CreateSheetForGroupName.  The myHeadingRow variable is not initialized with a value.  Therefore, the If statement runs and then exits the function setting myWs = Nothing.  I added Set myHeadingRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:L1") after the declaration and everything works perfectly!  THANK YOU so much for all of your time and effort!  HAPPY NEW YEAR!